# Import of twitterscraper returns 'NonType' error

Tags: python, pandas

I installed twitterscraper and then run this

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
import daterime as dt
import pandas as pd
```

but it turns out

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

plz help me out!

Comment: Welcome toSO. Please be specific and share all the code that produced  this error. The import of libraries does not produce such an error.

Comment: thank you for comment.. i installed pip install twitterscraper through anaconda prompt, and.. that's it! i only wrote those 3lines, and sadly, that produced this error.

Comment: Change ```daterime``` to ```datetime```

Comment: Also, have you installed twitterscraper? ```pip install twitterscraper```, in jupyter notebook ```!pip install twitterscraper```

Comment: thank you again. and yep i did it !pip install twitterscraper in jupyter notebook, and ran those 3 line correctly, and i've got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have the wrong version  of twitterscraper. Do this

```
pip install twitterscraper==0.2.7
```

In jupyter

```
!pip install twitterscraper==0.2.7
```

Comment: I changed the answer and it worked for me

Comment: hey.. you save my life.. you know what? i'm korean and now is 4:36 am haha

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember to accept the answer and update if it was what you wanted.행운을 빕니다!

Comment: merci beaucoup!!! Unfortunately, i faced another problem.. if you have time, check my another question.

Comment: Is it the totaltweet question that was closed? It is a little difficult to help without entire code. It was closed by another user because it was unclear what you wanted to acchieve. Be clearer on what doesn't work, what you've done and which libraries you are using.

Comment: BTW. I am going to change the title in this question so that i is clear what the problem was.