# Twitterscrapper error solution is throwing a different error

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

if i use twitterscraper-1.6.1

```
list_of_tweets = query_tweets('ukraine', limit=10, begindate=dt.date.today(), enddate=dt.date.today(), poolsize=20, lang='en')
```

i get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

if i use twitterscraper-0.2.7 as suggested at [Import of twitterscraper returns 'NonType' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100500)
i get unexpected keyword 'begindate'

I am trying to pull tweets using https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper and following along with the examples.